# Google Drive doesn't recognize my uploaded xes file

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, file-type

I tried to upload an xes file into Google Colab and for a new dataset, it just doesn't work.
Google Drive is mounted and the new file is stored exactly where the old one was and I just switched the path.

Here is the code I used:

```
!pip install pm4py

import pm4py
from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import importer as xes_importer

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
log = xes_importer.apply('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/BPI Challenge 2017.xes.gz')
```

For another file that is stored in the same folder, the code worked. I tried it with the .gz and the .xes file and it's the same - works for two other datasets I already had but not for multiple other ones I tried.

Now I get the following error message:

```
 File "<string>", line unknown
  SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for '/tmp/tmp0rajagivgz'
```

I tried unpacking the file first before uploading it (from gz to xes) but  it also doesn't work, just the file name is changing.

I assume, the problem is that Google Drive considers the file a zip file even though the file I uploaded originally isn't. On my desktop, both datasets (the old and the new one after unpacking) are recognized as xes.
I don't know why Drive doesn't upload the new dataset as the file that it is.

Do you have any recommendations?
Any explanation would be helpful.

Best,
Linda

Edit: added the code

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.